# How can I mysqldump all databases except the mysql schema?

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I want to backup all 200+ databases on a MySQL server to `all-dbs.sql`.

I want to exclude the `mysql` schema.

How can I do that?

Comment: No doubt about the possible - it's a dupe! Vote to close and point users to the original answer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to collect all the database names into a space delimited list. Use that for mysqldump

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
#
# Collect all database names except for
# mysql, information_schema, and performance_schema
#
SQL="SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN"
SQL="${SQL} ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema')"

DBLISTFILE=/tmp/DatabasesToDump.txt
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}" > ${DBLISTFILE}

DBLIST=""
for DB in `cat ${DBLISTFILE}` ; do DBLIST="${DBLIST} ${DB}" ; done

MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--routines --triggers --single-transaction"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} --databases ${DBLIST} > all-dbs.sql
```

**Give it a Try !!!**

Comment: Just for anyone here reading that is in a similar position to me - you can also just dump everything and manually remove the mysql schema from the dump file, to save time writing/running scripts

Comment: "Why should we care implementing a simple `--ignore-database` argument, look at this tiny script, it will do just fine."

Comment: It says `mysqldump: unknown option '--ignore-database'` don't know why, but when I used `--ignore-table=information_schema.*` it worked.

Comment: What language is the above script??!

Comment: It's always lovely to read the comments :)))

Comment: @TheStoryCoder It's written in english, but the programming language is bash :D

Comment: My MySQL instance has a `sys` database in it that looks like another DB for internal use that should be ignored.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller you are right. In fact, `innodb` would also need to be added for RDS instances (although it has no actual tables)

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA hello Sir, do we need to create empty databases before import the all-dbs.sql file? Thanks!

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA If it is Windows, string usually has \r (carriage return) which make s it overwrite values in concatenation. So, something like DB=$(echo "$DB" | tr -d '\r') before concatenation should be used.

Comment: You can skip the temp file in the middle with `group_concat(schema_name separator ' ')` (and make the discussion about EOL characters irrelevant)

Comment: @GrasDouble I don't know if your sarcastic. This 'tiny script' will not dump all dbs in single transaction

Comment: I was ranting at MySQL because I precisely had to dump all dbs excluding a few ones, which I suppose is a very common use case, and because of the lack of a `--ignore-database` argument we have to rely on complicated scripts as a workaround. The above script is fine, as it's the best we can do…

Comment: Just to expand a bit on the accepted answer above:
SELECT schema_name could become: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(schema_name SEPARATOR ' ') 
and you completly skip the for loop.