# Copy MySQL User but change HostName

Tags: mariadb, users, copy

I am migrating to a docker MariaDB setup and all my users were created w/ "Localhost". From what I read and tested ironically `'%'` excludes `localhost`. I want to copy my existing users adding a second entry utilizing `'%'` as the hostname. Any suggestions?

Comment: which mariadb version?

Comment: @danblack If you can tell me which version has a method to do this in that others don't I will use that version. As far as I know, it doesn't matter which version.

Comment: Why did you remove the `mariadb` tag?

Comment: Because its not mariadb specific IMO, there's no native tools I don't think so its going to be an SQL script, perhaps adding both mariadb and mysql would be OK just felt limiting to mariadb was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `SHOW CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost'` and `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'localhost'` for all the users fetched by

```
SELECT user, host 
  FROM mysql.user
 WHERE host = 'localhost'
```

and to replace all `'localhost'` entries by `'%'` in the returned statements.

Comment: I know how to replace with UPDATE but I'd like to copy the user and then change hostname.

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers It's not a problem to update an user already having grants. But if you want to copy some user you have to copy his grants too. The easiest way to do that is to fetch `SHOW CREATE USER` and `SHOW GRANTS FOR` then substitute hostname by desired value and then run that statements. There is no native tool to do that at once.

Comment: Yes I was hoping for something more descriptive than, run SQL against each user and then copy the output. If nobody makes a solution I'll likely script something myself but my SQL foo is limited.

Comment: You might find my [SQL User Backer](https://github.com/DEQ-Dave/SQLUserBacker) tool of use. It will extract all of the users and grants and all you'd have to do is change localhost to % and load the modified files.